# Error on changing permissions in serial port

Tags: raspbian-jessie, serial, uart, permissions

I have been trying to find a solution for 2 days but I wasn't able to find one. I want to change the permission of the /dev/ttyAMA0 but seems to be impossible. I tried with sudo chmod 777 /deb/ttyAMA0 but at the following minute the port recovered old permissions for read, write and execute. The next thing that I tried was writing an udev rule with the following code:
KERNEL=="ttyAMA0", MODE="0777, but nothing end with success.

I want to read information from an antenna that is connected on the serial port ttyAMA0, the problem is that I am not able to read the information unless I will give read permissions.

When I try to `sudo adduser $USER tty` the output is the following:The user pi' is already a member of tty'. Moreover, when I execute a script to access the /dev/ttyAMA0 the result is:

> Permission denied: '/dev/ttyAMA0'.

I have these permissions on ttyAMA0 port:

```
crw--w---- 1 root tty 204, 64 Jul 5 11:15 ttyAMA0
```

the output of `lsof /dev/ttyAMA0` is the following:

```
agetty 800 root 0u CHR 204,64 0t0 1157 /dev/ttyAMA0
agetty 800 root 1u CHR 204,64 0t0 1157 /dev/ttyAMA0
agetty 800 root 2u CHR 204,64 0t0 1157 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I used this command to kill the process:

```
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

Now I am able to change the permissions without any automatic change in permissions each minute. The problem now is that each time I reboot the Raspberry the permissions change to the default configuration.

I switched the serial ports `ttyAMA0` and `ttyS0` to get a better control of the Baudrate, that is the reason why the `ttyAMA0` port has `crw--w----` instead of `crw-rw----`.

I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the permissions?  What does not work if you leave the permissions alone?  You should not be changing the permissions.

Comment: I want to read information from an antenna that is connected on the serial port ttyAMA0, the problem is that I am not able to read the information unless I will give  read permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One plausible cause of your issue is that `/dev/ttyAMA0` is used as a boot console in `/boot/cmdline.txt`. You should remove the `console=/dev/xxx,115200` if you intend to use the serial port as a general-purpose device and not as a boot console.

Answer (score 1):

Please, don't touch the permissions, that's not a good way to get access.

Instead, add yourself to the group `tty` which owns the device and has read/write access:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyAMA0 
crw-rw---- 1 root tty 204, 64 Jun 20  2016 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

You may easily do that using:

```
sudo adduser $USER tty
```

`$USER` is the name you used to log in with (`echo $USER` on command line will show your name) so you can use that command 'as is' and do not need to change anything.

Comment: I have tried it and the output is the following:The user `pi' is already a member of `tty'. Moreover, when I execute a script to access the /dev/ttyAMA0 the result is: Permission denied: '/dev/ttyAMA0'. I have these permissions on ttyAMA0 port: crw--w---- 1 root tty     204,  64 Jul  5 11:15 ttyAMA0

Comment: @SergioPrieto try `lsof /dev/ttyAMA0` to find out if someone else's using the port?

Comment: the output of the lsof command is the following`agetty     800       root    0u   CHR 204,64      0t0 1157 /dev/ttyAMA0
agetty     800       root    1u   CHR 204,64      0t0 1157 /dev/ttyAMA0
agetty     800       root    2u   CHR 204,64      0t0 1157 /dev/ttyAMA0`

Comment: @SergioPrieto well, likely you have terminal sessions waiting for users on those terminals. try to `killall agetty`, but be careful, it might kill something useful =)

Comment: I used this command to kill the process:`sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service`, now I am able to change the permissions without any automatic change in permissions each minute. The problem now is that each time I reboot the Raspberry the permissions change to the default configuration.

Comment: @SergioPrieto once you have killed the process, you don't have to change the permissions, you should be able to access `/dev/ttyAMA0` easily, as long as you are in `tty` group. If you have just added yourself to this group, you'll need to logout/login again for things to work.

Comment: @SergioPrieto following your earlier message: "I have these permissions on ttyAMA0 port: crw--w----" -- this is strange, permissions on `/dev/ttyAMA0` should be `crw-rw----` -- owner and group can read and write.

Comment: I switched the serial ports ttyAMA0 and ttyS0 to get a better control of the Baudrate, that is the reason why the ttyAMA0 port has `crw--w----`

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are changing because another process is accessing the serial link.

You need to identify and deactivate that process (`ls -l /dev/ttyAMA0` will probably show the group).

Once that process is deactivated the permissions will be correctly set by Linux without you having to do anything else.